# CSS: fine tuning font size

Tags: css

Is there a way to control the font size other then the font-size property ?

**font-size:11px** is too large and **font-size:10px** is too small.

What are some other options to control the font size ?

Comment: Is what you're designing only going to be used in one browser and screen type? Fonts can easily shift by 1px or more between browsers, platforms, screen types and screen densities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several different units with font-size.  You could try `em`, `px`, `pt`, or a `%`. Try using a decimal value as well.

There are also several named sizes you could try as well; `xx-small`, `x-small`, `small`, `medium`, `large`, `x-large`, `xx-large`, `smaller`, and `larger`.

From: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

Comment: doesn't matter the unit, em pt % ex etc are always calculated to pixels, and if the font renderer doesn't support pixel fractions or monitor has a 1:1 pixel density, you will see no difference at all between 10.5 and 11

Answer (score 2):

you can use 10.5px as well, but it will be properly rendered only if the font renderer (for example direct2d/directdraw, gdi) supports fractions of pixels

you should use SVG fonts, that apparently do support pixel fractions sizes

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('fonts/myfont.svg') format('svg')
        /* other fonts format here */
    ;
}
```

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator - that is a cool webfont generator that includes svg fonts

hoping to be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Use `font-size: 10.5px;`

Other options can be found here at w3: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp
You can use `em` as your unit, or specify as a `%`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pt` or `em` instead `px`.